# После удаления из sqlte одного столбца ошибка

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Удалил ненужный столбец, поменял после етого DATEBASE_VERSSION и такая ошибка :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ContactFruit (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM ContactFruit
```

пишет что не так с методом :

```
 public List<Fruit> getAllFruits() {
        List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
                fruit.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                fruit.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                fruit.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

                fruitList.add(fruit);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return fruitList;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код класса для работы с БД.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того, как Вы повысили версию `DATEBASE_VERSION`, при подключении к БД был вызван метод `onUpgrade(...)`, который удалил существующую таблицу:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT);
```

Поэтому Вы и получаете соответствующее исключение. Вы пытаетесь добавить запись в таблицу, которой не существует.

После удаления таблицы, ее необходимо создать. Код метода `onUpgrade(...)` будет таким:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRUIT);
}
```